# What special search terms do I need to look up information on writing external BBS software packages?

Tags: haskell

I am looking into making a text based game that I wrote in Haskell into a BBS software package. I am having problems finding information on writing the simplest of BBS software such as a echo server. I have implemented a simple telnet server before, but never a BBS software package.

Am I not googling the correct keywords or is it that dead simple?

Ideally, I am looking for a link to an existing tutorial on making a BBS software package.

Comment: That's a pretty vague question.  And what Google is for; keep trying.

Comment: Just to clarify, I am talking about the 1990s service originally over a phone line using a modem. Not a modern website Bulletin Board System or a TCP Server, but a package for a BBS like Synchronet.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You probably want a "door development kit" that supports your language and BBS of choice. You'll have to consult the documentation for your specific BBS to determine what dropfiles and door routines it supports.

Comment: Great, thanks for giving me a place to start. I know what I need to look for. Thanks Again!

Answer (score 0):

I implemented a simple telnet based BBS a while back:

```
darcs get http://src.seereason.com/happstack-bbs/
```

Switching to a dial-up version might not be all that big of a change. In Linux the modem connection will just be some device like /dev/modem, and that you read and write like a file.

So, in Telnet.hs you would make a function like runTelnetIO that does the reads and writes to a file Handle instead of a Socket.

patches accepted ;)

That said, Telnet.hs is not the greatest code I ever wrote. I think I did it in a single sitting so I could release it as an April Fools Joke.